# Asterisk Server not accepting voice

Tags: asterisk

I have installed AsteriskNow server with FreePBX on Virtualbox.
I am using a Softphone(3cxphone) to test the system. 
I could able to connect to Asterisk and make calls. But I can't here anything what other end is saying.
Also the call is got cut after 8-10 seconds.

I configured and tested my microphone and it is working properly.

Harikrishnan

Comment: Have you checked for blocked firewall ports? If you are doing this in an isolated environment (not connected to the internet), try disabling all firewalls as a quick easy test to confirm whether or not it is a firewall issue. Also, is this noticed on both sides of the phone conversation or just one way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the firewall is blocked the RTP (and RTCP) traffic. The session is established with SIP, hence you can do calls and receive calls but You dont listen, because the media traffic is blocked. 
Then, You should open the */etc/asterisk/rtp.conf* file and edit the follow lines with the ports that You want use to RTP (and RTCP) protocol.

```
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
```

RTP protocol works over UDP, then You should open this UDP port range. (In your Server and if You are using NAT You should configure the port forwarding too.

Answer (score 1):

You need configure nat and firewall

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat

Comment: I configured them, but it is stll not working

Comment: Probably you need network expert or asterisk expert. Note, asterisk in virtualization is not for begginer.